# Как использовать метод custom_mail в битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, smtp

Моя цель - посылать имейлы в обработчике событий
Для этого я подключил плагин "Отправка электронной почты через SMTP" - https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/wsrubi.smtp/?PAGEN_2=2#tab-install-link

В файл  php_interface/init.php добавил строку
`include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/wsrubi.smtp/classes/general/wsrubismtp.php");`

Проверил -- через веб-интерфейс админки имейл отпавляется
Как мне отправлять имейлы из кода?
Нашел текст
`Для отправки писем модуль использует функцию custom_mail`

Нашел в коде

```
public_html/bitrix/modules/wsrubi.smtp/classes/general/wsrubismtp.php:    function custom_mail($to, $subject, $m ...
```

**Мой код**

```
<?php


require_once("php_fast_cache.php");
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/wsrubi.smtp/classes/general/wsrubismtp.php");

CModule::IncludeModule("security");
use \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug;
use Bitrix\Main\Mail\Event;


AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", Array("CreateEventHandler", "OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler"));

class CreateEventHandler
{
    // Handle event "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd"
    function OnAfterIBlockElementAddHandler(&$arFields)
    {
        if ($arFields["IBLOCK_ID"] == 14)
        {
               
          Event::send(array(
            "EVENT_NAME" => "SEND_NEW_BUILDING",
            "LID" => "s1",
            "C_FIELDS" => array(
                "EMAIL_TO" => "myEmail@gmail.ru",
                "TEXT" => "Текст сообщения"
            ),
          )); 

        }
    }
}
?>
```

В таблице вижу мой новый имейл (SUCCESS_EXEC = Y) -- выглядит, что все ок, **НО НА ПОЧТУ ИМЕЙЛ НЕ ПРИХОДИТ, ПРОВЕРЯЛ СПАМ И РАЗНЫЕ АДРЕСА**

В чем ошибка, где найти логи?

Настройки модуля
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки шаблона имейла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью данного модуля будут отправляться все отправленные письма автоматически.

Для отправки писем из Битрикс необходимо использовать стандартные функции для отправки

- [\Bitrix\Main\Mail\Event::send](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/mail/event/send.php)
- \Bitrix\Main\Mail\Event::sendImmediate

Всё это происходит средствами модуля [Mail](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=41&CHAPTER_ID=04558&LESSON_PATH=3911.4558), а установленный модуль является только транспортом для отправки писем - в данном случае отправка по SMTP.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Попробовал использовать этот метод -- на почту ничего не приходит, приложил код. Где найти логи, чтобы понять причину?